# CakePHP and connection pooling

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, connection-pooling

I am working on a website that needs to serve multiple requests from the same table simultaneously. We made a simple index page in CakePHP which draws some data from the database (10 rows, to be precise), and a colleague executed a test simulating 1000 users viewing the same page at the same time, meaning that 1000 identical requests would be issued to the database. The thing is that at around 500 requests, the database stopped being responsive, everything just froze and we had to kill the processes.

What comes to mind is that each and every request is executed on its own connection, and this would explain why the MySQL server was overwhelmed. From a few searches online, and on SO, I can see that PHP does not support connection pooling natively, as can be done in a Java application, for instance. Having based our app on CakePHP 2.5.3, however, I would like to think that there is some underlying mechanism that overcomes these limitations. Perhaps I am not doing something right?

Any suggestion is welcome, I just want to make sure to exhaust every possible solution.

Comment: Have you seen the `persistent` option in [database config](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#database-configuration)?

Comment: In my configuration, `persistent => 'false'` and in all honesty, I doubt it would be a good idea to force persistent connections to the database... What I mean to say is that at the current phase I am only recovering 10 rows from the database, and that's it, nothing more - why use a persistent connection? So in theory it should release any resources after the query, right?

Comment: If you don't want to have the overhead of setting up and destroying a connection every time your script runs or have tons of multiple connections, use ``persistent``. Are you sure you understand why your db halts? Did you read the logs to figure it out? Your db should be able to handle 500 simple 10 record selects since they are most probably query-cached and coming from memory so I'd guess other things are to blame. Also I hope you're not testing with ``debug`` set on.

Answer (score 0):

If results gonna be same for each query, you can cache the query result, then it will not send multiple request to database,
try this plugin:-
https://github.com/ndejong/CakephpAutocachePlugin